# Slow Android Studio after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio, upgrade, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-15.10

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu from Mate 15.10 to Xenial Xerus 16.04 LTS. Mate was totally stable and fast even while using Android Studio but after upgrade Android Studio has become very much slow. I even checked for swappiness and stuffs like that and now considering a fresh install of Mate 15.10 and all applications again. It will a lot of waste of time but cannot bear that slow Android Studio. Can anyone suggest me anything else so that I don't waste my time on installations.

Comment: I had the same problem several times when I tried to upgrade my Ubuntu. So if you don't want to spend too much time trying to fix this problem (it might has deeper problems and being too wide to fill only one question). The only solution on which it usually ended and not to spend too much time with it was unfortunately reinstallation.

Comment: That's sad! But I figured it out, so reinstalling now :(. BTW Thank you @Egel :)